# React componentDidMount fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch an api inside componentDidMount. The api result will be set to the component's state and the state mapped and passed to a children component.

If I fetch the api using the **fetch method inside** the componentDidMount everything works fine:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(apiToFetch)
        .then((result) => result.json())
        .then((result) => result.entries)
        .then((entries) => this.setState({ ...this.state, entries }))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

if I use **fetch inside a method and then call this method inside componentDidMount** nothing is rendered:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchApiToEntries(GLOBAL_PORTFOLIO_COLLECTION_API);
}

fetchApiToEntries(apiToFetch) {
    fetch(apiToFetch)
        .then((result) => result.json())
        .then((result) => result.entries)
        .then((entries) => this.setState({ ...this.state, entries }))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

I cannot understand what I am missing from the lifecycle. 
Shouldn't react do the following?

- Init the state
- Render
- Call componentDidMount
- Rerender

Here is my initial component:

```
export default class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            entries: []
        }

    }
    componentDidMount() {

        this.fetchApiToEntries(GLOBAL_PORTFOLIO_COLLECTION_API);
    }
    fetchApiToEntries(apiToFetch) {
        fetch(apiToFetch)
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((result) => result.entries)
            .then((entries) => {
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    entries
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Fade bottom>
                <div className="Portfolio">
                    <div className="Portfolio__title"><h4 className="color--gradient text--spacing">WORKS</h4></div>
                    <OwlCarousel {...options}>
                        {this.state.entries.map((item) => (
                            <PortfolioElement item={item} />
                        ))}
                    </OwlCarousel>
                    <AnchorLink href='#contact'><Button className="contact-button btn--gradient slider-button Services__button">Let's get in touch</Button></AnchorLink>
                </div>
            </Fade>
        )
    }
}
```

PortfolioElement is the actual component not being rendered.
Any advice?
Thank you.

**Edit:** both methods are not rerendering the component the right way (...something I didn't expect: I don't know why but if I call them twice in componentDidMount the component will render the right way). I think I am missing something in the state.

I have no error in the console and this is how I set my initial state:

```
this.state={entries:[]}
```

and this is what the actual entries looks like from the console:

```
 entries:
[0:{credits: "..."
    description: "..."
    featuredImage: {path: "portfolio/01.jpg"}
    firstImage: {path: "portfolio/firstimage.jpg"}
    secondImage: []
    slug: "..."
    tasks: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    title: "..."
    _by: "5beae6553362340b040001ee"
    _created: 1542123322
    _id: "5beaef3a3362340bf70000b4"
    _mby: "5beae6553362340b040001ee"
    _modified: 1542149308
},
1:{...}
]
```

My state after the fetch is the same way.

**UPDATE** I figured out that the the problem is: when the state changes the  component is not rerendering the child with the correct props. I called the API in an higher order component passed down the props and added a componentWillUpdate method forcing a state refresh that rerenders the component. Not the ideal solution but I am not figuring out other ways until now. Any advice?

Comment: I know the method binding in the constructor is missing.

Comment: *Shouldn't react do the following?* - it should. *if I use fetch inside a method and then call this method inside componentDidMount nothing is rendered* - this is unlikely. These two `componentDidMount` snippets should behave exactly the same way, as long as `apiToFetch` is the same. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: It should work, please check console log for any error or replicate this on codepen so it will be easy for other to debug the issue

Comment: Can you do a log and show us the structure of `result.entries`? Are you getting error in the console, network or browser?

Comment: I get no errors, and I have to edit my question: both methods give the same results. I think I am missing something in my initial state. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Idk what your api response is but I tested your code with a fake API and changed

```
fetchApiToEntries(apiToFetch){}
```

to Arrow Function ([Arrow Function](http://Arrow%20functions%20-%20JavaScript%20%7C%20MDN%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/.../Functions/Arrow_functions))

```
fetchApiToEntries = (apiToFetch) => {}
```

and it's working fine.

Full Example:

```
    export default class Portfolio extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                entries: []
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
          this.fetchApiToEntries('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        }
        fetchApiToEntries = (apiToFetch) => {
            fetch(apiToFetch)
                .then(result => result.json())
                .then((entries) => {
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        entries
                    })
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
        render() {
          const {entries} = this.state;
            console.log(entries);
            return (
                // Everything you want to render.
            )
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This code is workable without an arrow, so it's unwanted here.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried the same before, nothing changes, I have posted the api response in the question edit. By the way, mapping the state in a simple <li></li> instead of inside of a children component works fine. Wondering if I have to set the state in an higher order component and pass down the state as props even if I feel it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

do you need to bind fetchApiToEntries in the constructor or use fat arrows?

```
this.fetchApiToEntries = this.fetchApiToEntries.bind(this);
```

sorry I cant comment not enough rep

Comment: No, you don't need.

Comment: As stated in my comment, I know it's missing but it is not relevant in this case...

Comment: break point the bit where its setting the state and check whats in it.

as its binding all the ways down ( with the fat arrows) after the fetch and setState will trigger a re-render. my GUESS is this is not the this you want.